# How to disable line break conversion in Parallels Desktop?

Tags: parallels-desktop

When copying text between a Windows client and the OSX host Parallels converts line endings, which is a big nuisance. Can this be disabled?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be a common complaint based on my research but there currently is no setting to disable this behavior.

Comment: I also did a search to make sure this hasn't been answered before. Still, I hope someone has a trick/hack/whatever. I'm not afraid to change something in the config files for a VM, just to get rid of this constant annoyance.